# Define props with 2 optional types in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

In Typescript, I can define a var with 2 types like this

`foo: string | number = 'bar'`

How can I do the similar in Dart?

Comment: Not currently supported. There are a discussion about this topic on the GitHub issue tracker for the Dart language: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/83

Answer (score -2):

You can't do that in dart 2.

> Dart 2 is statically typed

https://dart.dev/faq#q-is-dart-a-statically-typed-language